# Using HTML buttons to add text to input and submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Goal**: Div with pin code input popups when a div is clicked (got this part). Enter pin code with buttons into a text input field of a form. When the correct 4 digits are entered, redirect to new page without having to press any sort of submit button.

**What I have**: I got the div that pops up by toggling the style of the div (display: hidden) The div which you have to click in order to get the pin code input div is named `s_wrapper_date_time`.

**What I need**: When any button is pressed it should be added to the text input field. And when the correct 4 digits are entered, automatically redirect to different page. Without any sort of submit button.

**Code**:
Home.php

```
<div id="code_input" class="s_input_code_content s_hidden">
        <form onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
            <input id="input_screen" class="s_input_text" type="text" maxlength="4"/>
            <div id="s_keypad">
                <button id="7" value="7" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">7</button>
                <button id="8" value="8" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">8</button>
                <button id="9" value="9" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">9</button>
                <button id="4" value="4" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">4</button>
                <button id="5" value="5" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">5</button>
                <button id="6" value="6" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">6</button>
                <button id="1" value="1" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">1</button>
                <button id="2" value="2" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">2</button>
                <button id="3" value="3" class="s_btn_g s_btn_number">3</button>
                <button id="0" value="0" class="s_btn_g s_btn_null">0</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".s_wrapper_date_time").click(function(){
                $("#code_input").toggleClass("s_hidden");
                $("#code_wrapper").toggleClass("s_hidden");
                //window.location.href = "overview.php?a=0";
            });
        </script>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you want us to write that for you?

Comment: You don't need jquery for this.  You could just as easily add an "onclick" tag, and call a function that sets everything up, and submits when conditions are satisfied.

Comment: So where are you actually stuck?  Handling a button click event?  Adding text to an input?  Redirecting a user?  Each of these things seems easily findable on Google.

Comment: I don't think people are reading closely enough. There's a "What I need" paragraph at the end of the question that explains exactly where OP was stuck. I did not find that too broad and found it easy to answer.

Comment: Im fairly new to jQuery, so I wasn't quite sure how to handle this. Should of probably said that somewhere. But Dexter's answer works for me. Thanks for your time guys and help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        pin_length = 4; //set your pin length.
        $(".s_btn_g").on("click", function(){
            $("#input_screen").val($("#input_screen").val() + $(this).text());
        });
        $("#input_screen").on("change", function(){
            if($(this).val().length === pin_length) $("form").submit(); //or window.location.href, whatever
        });
```

It really is better to use form names/ids and use the form action attribute, rather than using the submit to move the viewer down the page. Also, you can disable "Enter" key submits.